# selecting files with readdir

Tags: php, readdir

```
<?php
// open the current directory
$dhandle = opendir('.');
// define an array to hold the files
$files = array();

if ($dhandle) {
   // loop through all of the files
   while (false !== ($fname = readdir($dhandle))) {

      if (($fname != 'other') && ($fname != 'dd') && ($fname != 'index.htm') && ($fname != 'torcache.php')&& ($fname != 'error_log') && 
          ($fname != basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))) {
          // store the filename
          $files[] = (is_dir( "./$fname" )) ? "(Dir) {$fname}" : $fname;
      }
   }
   // close the directory
   closedir($dhandle);
}
```

what i would like to do is if the file starts with 'other' or 'dd' then to not include it in the loop $files; short of naming the whole filename in the !=, what can i do to exclude these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your checks:

```
(substr($fname, 0, 5) != 'other') && (substr($fname, 0, 2) != 'dd')
```

See [PHP substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php). It takes a string and returns a substring starting at the first number given (`0` means start of string) and with a length given by the second number (`5` for "other" and `2` for "dd").

So your complete statement would be:

```
if (
    (substr($fname, 0, 5) != 'other') &&
    (substr($fname, 0, 2) != 'dd') &&
    ($fname != 'index.htm') &&
    ($fname != 'torcache.php') &&
    ($fname != 'error_log') &&
    ($fname != basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))
) { ... }
```